# Avoid Thread.Sleep when no data in queue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer

Currently running a windows service which creates 5 threads and running a while loop. The thing is to retrieve data from a queue and do something with it, if no data, make the thread "sleep" for X minutes. How can avoid blocking those thread? Most of the time they are idling because of no data. Pseudocode:

```
public static void Main()
{
    //Create consumers
    Consumer con = new Consumer();
    Consumer con2 = new Consumer();
    Thread thr = new Thread(con.doJob);
    Thread thr2 = new Thread(con2.doJob);
    thr.Start();
    thr2.Start();
}

void doJob()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //Retrieve data
        if(data) {
        //Consume it
        } else {
        //Right now using Thread.Sleep(5 minutes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is nothing to do, then you SHOULD put the thread to sleep.  That's the point.  5 minutes seems way excessive -- just wait for 5 seconds, unless you know data comes in much slower than that.

Comment: You need some kind of signalling mechanism to wake the thread up rather than put it to sleep for an exact length of time. Arguably you shouldn't have threads here at all, you should instead use `await` with some kind of queue or channel mechanism.

Comment: Use a Blocking Collection type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: You could also try implementing some reactive queue so any subscriber would be notified that there is something to process.

Comment: This is for one producer and multiple consumers? Or are there multiple producers as well?

Comment: Are you in control of the `data` queue? Or do you only have control over the `Consumer`?

Comment: Based on your pseudocode, it seems you do not care about order of processing. Can you confirm this? Is it ok if data is being consumed out of order?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 I can confirm, doesn't matter the order. I retrieve the data from a queue (lets just say, connecting to a db and take data) and process it (consumer).

Comment: Alright, so you have one "producer", multiple "consumer"?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 Yes, one producer should be enough, the traffic is not high to consider multiple producers.

Comment: Are you able to control/modify the queue from the producer side and ensure that it is thread safe? Or are you only able to modify the consumer side?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 Only consumer, the producer just do a get to a jms client.

Comment: If you aren't able to build in some sort of notification system into the producer which would alert consumers to start processing, then it'll most likely require you to poll for data on the consumer side, meaning you'd need to have the consumer check for data and then sleep until the next check. So your current approach is probably what you would end up with.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps allowing whichever method adds data to the queue to also start the processing of the queue would work to your benefit.

In the example below, there is a list that can be added to by the `AddDataToQueue` method. This method will effectively add the item to the data queue, and then if the data is not already being processed it would start that as well. This would drain the queue of data to be processed, while still allowing items to be added to the list. When it is finished with the queue it goes back to a resting state, waiting for data being added to the queue to trigger the processing again.

See this code as an example:

```cs
        // this object is used to create a lock when checking the processing bool
        private static readonly object classLock = new object();

        // this flag is switched to true when processing starts
        private static bool processing = false;

        // the queue we are using
        public static List<string> DataQueue = new List<string>();
        public static async void AddDataToQueue(string data)
        {

            // add the data to the queue to be processed
            DataQueue.Add(data);


            // add a lock to the following section to ensure the bool is being checked without race conditions
            lock (classLock)
            {
                // if it's already in the midst of processing, it doesn't need to be triggered again
                if (processing)
                    return;

                // otherwise begin to process queue
                processing = true;
            }

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Process data here until queue is empty
                while (DataQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    // deal with the first index (essentially a first in first out queue)
                    Console.WriteLine(DataQueue[0]);
                    DataQueue.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                // reset the flag
                processing = false;
            });
        }
```

You'll notice (as @Charlieface had mentioned in the comments), that this is more of a signal to start processing rather than sleeping and periodically checking. You'll also notice that it is an `async` method. This is necessary to allow it to process without interrupting the other members which may add to the list.

A benefit with this approach is that your data is processed as fast as it is received, so you aren't dealing with information that is 5 minutes old (this doesn't matter in all cases, but certainly matters in some).

Comment: List<T> is not thread safe. The processing flag could cause race condition. BlockingCollection<T> would be a better fit.

Comment: @Night94 You're right about the race condition on the `processing` flag, I've gone and added a lock to the check. Does it look like the race condition would be avoided now? (I've tried this with thousands of tasks inserting thousands of data points and haven't come across any issues yet, but to verify)

Comment: Online material for systematic study: [Threading in C# - BASIC SYNCHRONIZATION - Locking - When to Lock](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_When_to_Lock) by ​Joseph Albahari.

Comment: With that in mind it seems like I may just be luckier than others. There are definitely some race conditions still present in this code. Thanks for the insight @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score -2):

You simply need a blocking buffer. The following Ada program illustrates what you need.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;             use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar;            use Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Calendar.Formatting; use Ada.Calendar.Formatting;

procedure Main is
   type Index_T is mod 10;
   type Circular_Buffer is array (Index_T) of Integer;

   protected buffer is
      entry write (Value : in Integer);
      entry Read (Value : out Integer);
   private
      Nums    : Circular_Buffer;
      W_Index : Index_T := 0;
      R_Index : Index_T := 0;
      Count   : Natural := 0;
   end buffer;

   protected body buffer is
      entry write (Value : in Integer) when Count < Nums'Length is
      begin
         Nums (W_Index) := Value;
         W_Index        := W_Index + 1;
         Count          := Count + 1;
      end write;

      entry read (Value : out Integer) when Count > 0 is
      begin
         Value   := Nums (R_Index);
         R_Index := R_Index + 1;
         Count   := Count - 1;
      end read;
   end buffer;

   Start_Time : constant Time := Clock;

   task type Consumer (Id : Positive);

   task body Consumer is
      Number  : Integer;
      elapsed : Duration;
   begin
      loop
         buffer.Read (Number);
         exit when Number = Integer'First;
         elapsed := Clock - Start_Time;
         Put_Line
           ("Consumer" & Id'Image & " read" & Number'Image & " after " &
            Image (elapsed));
      end loop;
      Put_Line ("Consumer" & Id'Image & " terminating.");
   end Consumer;

   C1 : Consumer (1);
   C2 : Consumer (2);

begin
   for I in 1 .. 10 loop
      buffer.write (I);
      buffer.write (I);
      Put_Line
        ("Producer wrote" & I'Image & " after " & Image (Clock - Start_Time));
      delay 10.0;
   end loop;
   buffer.write (Integer'First);
   buffer.write (Integer'First);
   Put_Line ("Producer terminating.");
end Main;
```

The protected object named buffer has a condition associated with the read entry which causes a task calling the read entry to suspend when count = 0. In other words, the consumer tasks will suspend when the buffer is empty. In Ada suspended tasks are placed into an implicit entry queue and are given access to the object in FIFO order when the boundary condition evaluates to True, which in this case is "count > 0".

The output of this program, including elapsed time measurements is:

```
Producer wrote 1 after 00:00:00
Consumer 2 read 1 after 00:00:00
Consumer 1 read 1 after 00:00:00
Producer wrote 2 after 00:00:10
Consumer 1 read 2 after 00:00:10
Consumer 2 read 2 after 00:00:10
Producer wrote 3 after 00:00:20
Consumer 2 read 3 after 00:00:20
Consumer 1 read 3 after 00:00:20
Producer wrote 4 after 00:00:30
Consumer 1 read 4 after 00:00:30
Consumer 2 read 4 after 00:00:30
Consumer 1 read 5 after 00:00:40
Consumer 2 read 5 after 00:00:40
Producer wrote 5 after 00:00:40
Producer wrote 6 after 00:00:50
Consumer 1 read 6 after 00:00:50
Consumer 2 read 6 after 00:00:50
Consumer 1 read 7 after 00:01:00
Consumer 2 read 7 after 00:01:00
Producer wrote 7 after 00:01:00
Consumer 1 read 8 after 00:01:10
Producer wrote 8 after 00:01:10
Consumer 2 read 8 after 00:01:10
Producer wrote 9 after 00:01:20
Consumer 2 read 9 after 00:01:20
Consumer 1 read 9 after 00:01:20
Producer wrote 10 after 00:01:30
Consumer 1 read 10 after 00:01:30
Consumer 2 read 10 after 00:01:30
Producer terminating.
Consumer 1 terminating.
Consumer 2 terminating.
```

The main task acts as the producer. It iterates through a loop 10 times. Each time it writes a value to the buffer twice and then delays (sleeps) for 10 seconds.
The consumer tasks terminate when they read the value Integer'First (which is the most negative value of type Integer) from the buffer.

Comment: The poster mentioned that they cannot modify the producer in this situation, a blocking buffer won't suffice. They need to just poll for information on the consumer side.

Comment: How, then, does the information flow from the producer to the consumer? It must be written to some data structure or I/O port. If so, whatever receives the information can be modified to post the information to a blocking queue so that multiple consumers can process the data.